# Multiple beside barplots with different variables in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I have three lists in R like these;

```
> list1<-list(Joseph=12, Johan=10, Dave=15,Steve=3,Jo=8)
> list2<-list(Joseph=12, David=10,George=2,Damian=20,Louis=2)
> list3<-list(Bill=22,David=2,Peter=2,Dave=18,Sebastian=8,William=3)
```

each column has a name label and a numeric score.

I want to display 3 barcharts, one beside the other; each barchart plots the 3 main scored names for each list, saving the label.

For instance, the first barplot shows Dave,Joseph,Johan with heights 15,12,10. The second barplot shows Damian,Joseph and David with heights 20,12 and 10, while the third barplot shows Bill,Dave,Sebastian with heights 22,18 and 8.

I found only examples where the very same variables are plotted in multiple barplots one beside the other in different experiments, but here nominally variables might keep changing from a barplot to another.

How to achieve my goal?

Comment: did you really want `Johan` twice in `list1`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `par` and `mfcol`/`mfrow` for this:

```
par(mfcol=c(1,3))
barplot(unlist(list1))
barplot(unlist(list2))
barplot(unlist(list3))
par(mfcol=c(1,1))
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Using multiplot function given in the [link](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Multiple_graphs_on_one_page_%28ggplot2%29/). I am also using ggplot2 and reshape2 :

```
p1<-ggplot(melt(data.frame(list1)),aes(x=variable,y=value))+geom_bar(stat='identity')
p2<-ggplot(melt(data.frame(list2)),aes(x=variable,y=value))+geom_bar(stat='identity')
p3<-ggplot(melt(data.frame(list3)),aes(x=variable,y=value))+geom_bar(stat='identity')
multiplot(p1, p2, p3, cols=1)
```

Another option is to use grid.arrange() in the gridExtra package:

```
grid.arrange(p1, p2,p3,ncol=3)
```

[image]

Comment: Would this be possible with `facet_wrap` after placing the three lists as a single datasets with a grouping column for each lists?

Comment: Possible. X axis are different for the 3 plots above. facet_wrap will give same axis for all the plots. So the plots will be different when some names are missing for some groups.